# Testing a package before submitting to Melpa

Tags: package-repositories

I'm going through the instructions at https://github.com/melpa/melpa/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.org to submit a package to Melpa. I would like to test to see if my recipe installs the package properly into a vanilla emacs which does not interfere with my current emacs and its packages.

The Melpa page says this can be done via

```
EMACS_COMMAND=/path/to/emacs make sandbox INSTALL=<NAME>
```

I'm befuddled. I get that the first part of this sets a variable in my bash shell and the NAME is the name of the package, but I don't understand the -make sandbox- part or how this would be run. Could anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: You have to clone the melpa repo and then in that directory run the makefile target [sandbox](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/blob/3ac02c053619ab01b13e1c48ab64c7a963df97a1/Makefile#L119) with that command from your question (should even work with just `make sandbox INSTALL=<NAME>`)

Comment: @Hubisan: thanks for getting me started. I had followed the instructions up to the `make sandbox` command, including forking & cloning the melpa repo. The critical missing step for me was that I needed to backtrack in the instructions. Specifically: I had to copy my `<NAME>` receipe into the recipes folder of the melpa fork, run `make recipes/<NAME>`, and then to run `make sandbox INSTALL=<NAME>`. Thanks again.